# Потеря текста в TextView после поворота экрана

Tags: android

У меня в программе после нажатия на кнопку в TextView выводится произвольный строковый элемент из массива строк, так вот после того, как меняется ориентация экрана, текст в TextView теряется, то есть меняется на тот, что был при запуске приложения, что может быть причиной этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana)

Comment: Спасибо!) Плохо я, видимо, гуглил)